# titleForHeaderInSection is overlapping the UISearch field

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiscrollview, uisearchbar

I'm having a problem where the titleForHeaderInSection is overlapping the UISearch field when a user scrolls the table.

I'm using the following code to offset a prior problem I had where the sectionIndexTitlesForTableView was overlapping the Cancel button. Now I have the section titles overlapping the UISearch field. Here's the code I have:

> -(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
>       searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,MAX(0,scrollView.contentOffset.y),320,44);

}

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try clipping the sub views. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277159/iphone-how-to-prevent-subview-from-overlapping-tab-bar) similar post for more information